# Не получается обработать POST данные node.js

Tags: php, node.js, express

Ребят, объясните, пожалуйста, что я делаю не так?

Сервер express. Отправляю запрос cURL'ом, php нормально обрабатывает.

Запрос такой:

```
$ch = curl_init();
$arr = ['email' => $email, 'password' => $password];  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,"http://site/send");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $arr);  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_exec($ch);
curl_close ($ch);
```

Обрабатываю все на сервере node.js, данные не приходят.

Обработчик:

```
var   express       = require("express"),    
    bodyParser       = require("body-parser");

var urlencodedParser = bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false});
var app = express();

app.post("/send", urlencodedParser, function (req, res) {   
  var email = req.body.email,
  password = req.body.password;
  console.log(email, password);
});

app.listen(80);
```

Что не так? Почему данные не обрабатываются?

`console.log(res.body)` тоже вообще ничего не выводит.

Comment: где ты `console.log(res.body)` вызываеш?